# Cannot inject Solr Server into app using Spring through @Autowired

Tags: spring, maven, solr, jersey, autowired

I am currently having an issue with trying to inject a solr server instance from a bean into my code.  I get a `NullPointerException` and have checked the server instance itself and verified that it is null.  I can create the server without injecting it just fine.

My spring.xml file declares the bean like this:

```
<bean id="solrServer" class="org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer">`
     <constructor-arg index="0" value="${solr.serverUrl}" />
</bean>

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="my.base.package" />
```

where the value `${solr.serverUrl}` has been confirmed to be correct.

The web.xml file has the Context Listener in it:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring.xml</param-value>
</context-param> 

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>     

<servlet>
    .
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
    </servlet-class>
    .
</servlet>
```

The code that I am trying to inject this bean is being `@Autowired` in as follows:

```
34    @Component
35    public class GenericClassImpl implements GenericClass{
36  
37        @Autowired
38        private SolrServer solrServer;
39  
40        public String doQuery(String query){
41            try{          
42                    SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery(query);           
43                    QueryResponse rsp = solrServer.query(solrQuery);
44                    SolrDocumentList docs = rsp.getResults();
45          
46                    return docs.toString();
47            }catch(Exception e){
48                e.printStackTrace();
49            }
50        }
51    }
```

I have tried to use the `@Qualifier("solrServer")` along with the `@Autowired` and that did not work either.

This is all being done using maven, which doesn't seem to have any issues itself.  The output I am getting is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ...GenericClassImpl.doQuery(GenericClassImpl.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1483)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1414)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1363)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1353)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:414)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:708)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:594)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1675)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Again, if I do

```
SolrServer solrServer = new HttpSolrServer(serverUrl);
```

the code works just fine and I can perform queries on the solr server.
Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong that this will not inject?

The code that obtains an instance of the `GenericClassImpl` is

```
public class GenericServiceImpl implements GenericService{

    protected GenericClass gc;

    @GET
    @Path({pathParam})
    public String doGet(@PathParam({pathParam}) String pathParam, 
                        @DefaultValue("*:*") @QueryParam("q") String query){

            gc = SearchFactory.getInstance().getGenericClass(pathParam);        
            return gc.doQuery(query);
        }
    }
```

And the `SearchFactory` is

```
public class SearchFactory{

    private static SearchFactory instance;

    private SearchFactory(){}

    public static SearchFactory getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new SearchFactory();
        return instance;
    }

    public GenericClass getGenericClass(String type){

        GenericClass result = null;

        if(type.toLowerCase().equals("case1")){
            result = new GenericClassImpl1();
            return result;
        }
        else if(type.toLowerCase().equals("case2")){
            result = new GenericClassImpl2();
            return result;
        }
        else throw new Exception();
    }
}
```

Both the `GenericClassImpl1` and `GenericClassImpl2` extend `GenericClassImpl` and are currently empty.

Comment: Could you show us the code in which you obtain an instance of GenericClassImpl?

Comment: I just added in the code that obtains an instance of it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `@Autowired` to work you need to obtain your `GenericClassImpl` instances from Spring. If you don't do this Spring will not autowire the dependencies.

You cannot instantiate them using the `new` keyword and use dependency injection techniques.

What you can do is hold a static reference to your `ApplicationContext` and then pull instances of the relevant bean from them in your `getGenericClass` method.

This is actually a good use case for the ServiceLocator pattern, as discussed in the Spring documentation.

Comment: What I ended up just doing and it worked beautifully was throwing a Component on the SearchFactory, GenericClassImpl1, and GenericClassImpl2 classes and using Autowired on new instance variables within them and just returning those private variables, letting spring handle their construction and be able to manage their lifecycle